# form.js error in MOSS 2007

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007

All of a sudden our development sharepoint publishing stopped working. I am not able to add any new items to Lists. Following are screenshots in different browser when trying to add a new item.

**Internet Explorer 7** :
JavaScript error occurs soon after I hover over the rich text editor. There are no required fields but still editor says I have to fill in all required fields and the form does not submit.
[alt text http://www.codegeeks.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/1.JPG](http://www.codegeeks.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/1.JPG)

**Firefox** : Rich text editor is not shown. Data gets added to the list without any issues but this is not what I want.

[alt text http://www.codegeeks.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/2.JPG](http://www.codegeeks.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/2.JPG)

**Internet explore 8** : Same as IE7.
[alt text http://www.codegeeks.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/error.JPG](http://www.codegeeks.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/error.JPG)

I tried clearing the cache, Restarting the server and iis, Cleared Temp folder for asp.net but nothing helped. It doesn't look like a JavaScript error to me. Any idea why this happens?

Our MOSS2007 Standard edition runs on Windows Server 2003 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is resolved ;-)

We had a user control which had a `<form>` tag. So nested form tags caused the issue.